# Count Same Row Value As One in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this :

```
Id     Subdistrict   District
-----------------------------
1      K             S
2      K             S
3      M             S
4      J             B
5      J             B
```

If the same subdistrict (and also district) value will count as 1 and i want it to return a result like this  :

> Subdistrict = 3 (Because there are only K, M, and J Subdistrict)
>
> District    = 2 (Because there are only S and B District)

How do i write the sql query? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [Count function with Distinct](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php), to count the number of unique rows (**non-null values**) for a field.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Subdistrict) AS number_of_subdistricts, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT District) AS number_of_districts 
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Hey it works well, thanks for your answer it really helps me :)